# MYSQL: multiple functions in query String

Tags: mysql, substring, substr

the following query is not working in MYSql (a Trigger)

```
set new.uniq = SUBSTR(md5(concat(new.lat, '-', new.lon)),0,5)
```

only if i delete the SUBSTR it will give me an correct output

```
set new.uniq = md5(concat(new.lat, '-', new.lon))
```

Comment: Please, can you put what `new.uniq`, `new.lat` and `new.lon` do?

Comment: If you want the leftmost characters, you can use the `LEFT` function instead of `SUBSTR`. For example, if you want the leftmost five characters  `LEFT(expr,5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the zero:

```
set new.uniq = SUBSTR(md5(concat(new.lat, '-', new.lon)),0,5)
                                                         ^
```

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('whatever', 0, 5) --> returns empty string
SELECT SUBSTR('whatever', 1, 5) --> returns 'whate'
```

Change the zero to a 1 and you should be fine:

```
set new.uniq = SUBSTR(md5(concat(new.lat, '-', new.lon)),1,5)
```